# Find a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$ with each main diagonal entries $0$, and with $A^2 = -I.$

Tags: matrices

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem.

I'm not certain what is meant by "each main diagonal entries 0". Does this mean:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$
I'm also not sure what it means by $A^2 = -I$?

From Wikipedia, I gathered that the identity matrix is an $n \times n$ square matrix with one's on the main diagonal and zero's elsewhere. What would would be considered the main diagonal?

Comment: [Main diagonal means this](https://www.google.it/search?q=main+diagonal&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=XOjZVtnRLMGvsAHQ0J7oCA).

Comment: $I$ is called the identity matrix because if $B$ is any 2x2 matrix then $IB=BI=B$ and no other 2x2 matrix will do this for all $B$.

Answer (score 7):

The main diagonal runs from the top left to the bottom right, so you're looking for a matrix like

$$A = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 0 & a \\ b & 0 \end{array}\right]$$
such that $A^2 = -I$. This can be done by trial and error, or by writing a system of a few equations after finding what $A^2$ is.

Comment: +1. "a system of a few equations " = **one** equation, repeated twice.

Comment: How do we come up with the system of equation?

Answer (score 0):

Since $A^2=-I$ the only possibilities for the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm i$.

Now, if your matrix is real, the characteristic polynomial is a monic quadratic polynomial with $i$ or $-i$ as a root. The only possibility is $x^2+1$.

Therefore $\det(A)=1$.

Conversely, if $\det(A)=1$, since $tr(A)=0$ the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $x^2+1$.  Then $A$ has two eigenvalues $\pm i$ with algebraic multiplicuty $1$. Hence $A$ is diagonalisable and then 
$$A=P \left[ \begin{array}{cc} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{array}\right] P^{-1} \Rightarrow A^2=P(-I)P^{-1}=-I$$

So the problem reduces to finding all such matrices of determinant 1. It is easy to find ALL matrices which satisfy the given condition of determinant 1, and these are all solutions to the question.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Comment: I didn't downvote but your solution is all too complicated for such a simple task. Just write it down and solve $ab=-1$. Done.

Answer (score 0):

From the relation given that $A^2 =-I$
We get an annihilating polynomial $p(x)=x^2+1$
And clearly the minimal polynomial of A divides this and hence the roots are $i$ and $-i$.
Just choose any a,b such that their product is $-1$ and you'll get your matrix..the prod has to be  $-1$ since the product of the eigenvalues is the determinant and for your matrix this comes out to be $-ab$. So $$-ab=1$$

Comment: Why simple when I can make it really complicated...

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: I mean that your answer is too complicated - especially for a person who does not know what the main diagonal is.